# Reading a specific line of a csv file and adding into array

Tags: c++

I would like to select a specific line of a csv file and add its values into an array.

For exemple if I select "two", the xyz array will be {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

Could someone help me ?

test.txt :

```
one,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
two,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
three,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

A simplified version of my program :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int xyz [8];
    char name[10];
    vector<string> word;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Name ?");
    scanf("%s", &name); // Input : two

    ifstream fichier("test.txt", ios::in);

    if(fichier)
    {
        string ligne;
        while(getline(fichier, ligne))
        {
            istringstream ss(ligne);
            std::string token;
            getline(ss,token,',');
            //cout << token << endl;
            if (token == name) {
                //printf("Correct name\n");
                while(getline(ss,ligne,',')){
                    cout << i;
                    cout << "-->";
                    cout << ligne << endl;
                    //How to : xyz[i] = ligne; ? 
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //printf("%d\n", xyz[0]); // Output : 0
    //printf("%d\n", xyz[7]); // Output : 7
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) What help do you need exactly? The code you posted is incomplete so a lot of guessing would be necessary to know where exactly you got stuck

Comment: "some things" would do the following: 1) read a line 2) split the line by commas 3) check if the first column is equal to `name`, 4) store the other columns into xyz. Which one are you having trouble with? Also, there are _LOTS_ of duplicate questions about this.

Comment: Thank you @Botje for your explanation.
I managed to do the 1) 2) 3) I guess but now i'm a little bit lost for the last part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int xyz [8];
    char name[50];
    int i = 0;
    //int n;
    printf("Name ?");
    scanf("%s", &name); // Input : two

    ifstream fichier("test.txt", ios::in);
    if(fichier)
    {
        string ligne;
        while(getline(fichier, ligne))
        {
            istringstream ss(ligne);
            std::string token;
            getline(ss,token,',');
            if (token == name) {
                while(getline(ss,ligne,','))
                {
                    //std::istringstream(ligne) >> n;
                    //xyz[i] = n;
                    xyz[i] = std::stoi(ligne);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fichier.close();
    }
    printf("%d\n", xyz[0]); // Output : 0
    printf("%d\n", xyz[7]); // Output : 7
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `xyz[i] = std::stoi(ligne);` is a slightly more common way to do the same thing. The stoi function converts a string to an intger.

Comment: Thank you @john :)